# How to sum up a range of numbers in a report, by defining the ranging using the report's multiple rows' name plus multiple columns' names? [Reduce]

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to share two found solutions to my question attached - how to calculate Cell: E5, when there could be more PROJECTS added behind Column: L and more ACCTS added after Row: 6.

[My question attached - how to calculate Cell: E5?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2ad0.png)